# debug.log file not found in wordpress using xampp on mac

Tags: wordpress, debugging, xampp

I have already put that code in wp-config.php file:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

but it does not create the debug.log file in wp/contents.

I was wondering if someone could help me with this.

Thanks.

I also tried using this code in wp-config:

```
@ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );
```

I have also set the location of file myself instaed of true but it did not work out.

Answer (score 0):

Also add `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` to wp-config.php.

And, be aware that the file is not created until the first logged event.